# CSS Style TD bottom border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the bottom border of a TD. The attached image shows this working as I'd like but the border is slightly too long, I'd like it to match the width of the blue cell above it.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: #5B86EE;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #A0A0A0;
  border-top: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-left: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-right: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  display: table-cell;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #5B86EE;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #640000;
  border-top: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-left: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-right: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%%" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tab">1</td>
      <td class="active">2</td>
      <td class="tab">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have no control over the HTML being used, but I can change the CSS.
Is there anyway to make the bottom border match the width of the cell excluding the left or right border width ?

Also viewing this in Firefox and the border over hang is on the other end, so on the left not the right.

Comment: The code has been converted to a snippet which does not show the problem at least on my IOS Safari. Could you check that something hasn’t changed and that you are still getting the problem.

Comment: It still shows the problem for me on firefox

Comment: @AHaworth I can see what (I think) the user is asking about on desktop Chrome.

Comment: @DBS thanks, yes I see it now (Chrome/Windows 10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element instead of a bottom border:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.active,
.tab {
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: #5B86EE;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #A0A0A0;
  border-top: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-left: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-right: solid 3px #E1E1E1;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.active:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #640000;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%%" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tab">1</td>
      <td class="active">2</td>
      <td class="tab">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks that displays correctly. However I have no control over the HTML so I can't remove the active class from the TD. How would I use this with the active class ?

Comment: just add active above the tab - see edit